# Compare mysql select to table and only use results with no match

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have created the following query which selects the data I need

```
SELECT par.wo, l.addr, eml.maildate, lp.workdate
FROM parsed AS par, emails AS eml, list AS l, locateparsed AS lp
WHERE par.status != 0 AND eml.id = par.origid AND par.wo = l.wo AND par.wo = lp.wo
```

Is it possible to have each returned row check in a "completed" table for a matching 'wo' and not output it if there is a match using one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why comma delimited tables in from irritate me so much, you just dont see the obvious-ness of join type use. try this:

```
SELECT
  par.wo,
  l.addr,
  eml.maildate,
  lp.workdate
FROM
  parsed AS par
  INNER JOIN emails AS eml      ON eml.id = par.origid
  INNER JOIN list AS l          ON par.wo = l.wo
  INNER JOIN locateparsed AS lp ON par.wo = lp.wo
  LEFT  JOIN completed          ON par.wo = completed.wo
WHERE
  par.status != 0 
  AND completed.wo IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i needed.